# Corona SDK - Removing drawn line group and then drawing again

Tags: lua, null, drawing, coronasdk

I'm trying to remove any lines I've drawn with a widget button and then allow the player to draw again.  I've tried to delete the group several times...and it works...but then when I go to draw again it crashes!  Any help with this scenario?

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

local widget = require( "widget" )

local lines = {}
local lineGroup = display.newGroup()
local prevX,prevY
local isDrawing = false
local i = 0

local kittenCrate = display.newRect(10,10,25,25)
physics.addBody(kittenCrate, "dynamic", { density = 1, friction = 0.5, bounce = 1.6})


local function distanceBetween(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    local dist_x = x2 - x1
    local dist_y = y2 - y1
    local distanceBetween = math.sqrt((dist_x*dist_x) + (dist_y*dist_y))
    return distanceBetween
end

local function drawLine(e)
    if(e.phase == "began") then
        prevX = e.x
        prevY = e.y
        isDrawing = true
        i = i + 1
    elseif(e.phase == "moved") then
        local distance = distanceBetween(prevX, prevY, e.x, e.y)
        if(isDrawing and distance < 100) then
            if(lines[i]) then lineGroup:remove(i) end
            lines[i] = display.newLine(prevX, prevY, e.x, e.y)
            lines[i]:setColor(255, 255, 0)
            lines[i].width = 5

            local dist_x = e.x - prevX
            local dist_y = e.y - prevY
            physics.addBody(lines[i], "static", { density = 1, friction = 0.5, bounce = 1, shape = {0, 0, dist_x, dist_y, 0, 0} } )
            lineGroup:insert(lines[i])
        end
    elseif(e.phase == "ended") then
        isDrawing = false
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch",drawLine)




local function handleButtonEvent( event )

    if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
        print( "Button was pressed and released" )

    end

end

-- Create the widget
local button1 = widget.newButton
{
    left = 100,
    top = 200,
    id = "button1",
    label = "Remove Rifts",
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code to the below and it works ok but not perfect. You have to follow your code to see exactly what it does. Although it is strange that Corona crashes when not finding your object.

```
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

local widget = require( "widget" )

local lines = {}
local lineGroup = display.newGroup()
local prevX,prevY
local isDrawing = false
i = 0

local kittenCrate = display.newRect(10,10,25,25)
physics.addBody(kittenCrate, "dynamic", { density = 1, friction = 0.5, bounce = 1.6})


local function distanceBetween(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    local dist_x = x2 - x1
    local dist_y = y2 - y1
    local distanceBetween = math.sqrt((dist_x*dist_x) + (dist_y*dist_y))
    return distanceBetween
end

local function drawLine(e)
    if(e.phase == "began") then
        prevX = e.x
        prevY = e.y
        isDrawing = true
        i = i + 1
        lineGroup.isVisible =true
    elseif(e.phase == "moved") then
        local distance = distanceBetween(prevX, prevY, e.x, e.y)
        if(isDrawing and distance < 100) then
            if(lines[i]) then lineGroup:remove(i) end
            lines[i] = display.newLine(prevX, prevY, e.x, e.y)
            lines[i]:setColor(255, 255, 0)
            lines[i].width = 5

            local dist_x = e.x - prevX
            local dist_y = e.y - prevY
            physics.addBody(lines[i], "static", { density = 1, friction = 0.5, bounce = 1, shape = {0, 0, dist_x, dist_y, 0, 0} } )
            lineGroup:insert(lines[i])
        end
    elseif(e.phase == "ended") then
        isDrawing = false
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("touch",drawLine)




local function handleButtonEvent( event )

    if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
        print( "Button was pressed and released" )
i=0
lineGroup.isVisible = false

    end

end

-- Create the widget
local button1 = widget.newButton
{
    left = 100,
    top = 200,
    id = "button1",
    label = "Remove Rifts",
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent
}
```